# Xcode 13 - turn off auto import feature

Tags: settings, disable, xcode13

Xcode 13 introduced automatic imports.
Anyone know if and how it can be turned off? I could not find anything in Xcode preferences nor online.

Comment: I find this is more obnoxious than helpful, most of the time imports meaningless frameworks just because I made a typo while coding (which I do all the time).

Comment: This is just randomly guessing at imports. The Xcode team has outdone itself on this one.

Comment: wish we can turn off this feature, the popup autocomplete suggestion is more dumb, just give us the option to show all the suggestion

Comment: I just lost a boatload of time because I added an if statement to a years-old file and my project suddenly stopped building, with dozens of bogus errors. I traced it back to an utterly uncalled-for and incorrect import statement that Xcode added behind my back. WTF, Apple.

Comment: This has broken our build a dozen times in the last two months.

Answer (score 5):

In XCode 13.1 there are no settings for that. Unfortunately :(

If everyone add the feedback about this feature, maybe we can improve xcode! https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/
Also i've made a radar https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4948759620354048. Leave your comments there to show the activity.

Comment: did they tested this feature? it's buggy.